# Characterization of linear flows in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: differential-topology

Let $\varphi:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ be a flow, that is,
a $C^\infty$ map such that $\varphi(0,p) = p$ for every $p\in\mathbb R^n$
and $\varphi(t+s,p) = \varphi(s,\varphi(t,p))$ for every $p\in \mathbb R^n$ and $t,s\in\mathbb R$.

Lets suppose that for every $t\in\mathbb R$, the map $\varphi_t:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$, $\varphi_t = \varphi(t,\cdot)$ is a linear map, so $\varphi_t$ is in
particular a diffeomorphism. I want to prove that there exist a $n\times n$ real matrix $A$ such that $\varphi_t = e^{tA}$, so I would be very pleased if someone gives me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Since $e^{tA}$ needs to appear in some way, and it is the solution of
the ordinary differential equation system $y'(t) = A y(t)$, when $y(0) = 1$.

Comment: What is your definition of flow?

Comment: @Jose27 I edited the post so now it is included. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hint(Rough Sketch): Observe for each fixed $t$ we have
\begin{align}
\varphi^t(x+y) = \varphi^t(x)+\varphi^t(y)
\end{align}
which is a Cauchy functional equation where $\varphi^t$ is continuous. Observe, if
\begin{align}
\varphi^t(nx) = n\varphi^t(x)
\end{align}
for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ which leads us to show that
\begin{align}
\varphi^t(q x)= q\varphi^t(x)
\end{align}
where $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. By continuity, it follows $\varphi^t(\alpha x) = \alpha \varphi^t(x)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, consider the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\varphi^t(x) = \varphi^t(\alpha_1 e_1 + \ldots +\alpha_n e_n) = \sum^n_{k=1}\alpha_k \varphi^t(e_k)
\end{align} 
which means
\begin{align}
\varphi^t(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\varphi^t(e_1), \ldots, \varphi^t(e_n)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1\\
\alpha_2\\
\vdots\\
\alpha_n
\end{pmatrix}
=A(t)x.
\end{align}
Hence we now have
\begin{align}
\varphi^t(x) = A(t)x \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d}{dt}\varphi(t, x) = A'(t)x = A'(t)A^{-1}(t)\varphi(t, x) = B(t)\varphi^t(x).
\end{align}
Thus, solving the above differential equation in $t$ yields
\begin{align}
\varphi(t, x) = e^{\int^t_0 B(\tau)\ d\tau}x.
\end{align}
Finally, using the property
\begin{align}
\varphi(t, \varphi(s, x)) = \varphi(t+s, x)
\end{align}
we see that
\begin{align}
e^{\int^t_0 B(\tau)\ d\tau}\left[e^{\int^s_0 B(\tau)\ d\tau}x \right] = e^{\int^{t+s}_0 B(\tau)\ d\tau}x.
\end{align}
Denote
\begin{align}
f(t) = \int^t_0B(\tau)\ d\tau
\end{align}
then it follows we have the following functional equation
\begin{align}
f(t)f(s) = f(t+s)
\end{align}
which leads to 
\begin{align}
f(t) = e^{tA}
\end{align}
where $A$ is a constant matrix.

Comment: Well, I was asking for a hint only, but thanks

Comment: Ops. My bad for spoiling the fun.

Comment: However, there are still a lot of details that I have skipped.  So, see if you could fill in all the details.

Comment: That $\varphi^t$ is linear implies that $\varphi^t(\alpha x) = \alpha\varphi^t(x)$ for $\alpha$ real immediately or I am missing something?

Comment: You are right. I was not assuming it's linear.

Comment: Basically, you could forget what I said up to the point where I get $\varphi^t(x) = A(t)x$.